# SOLR The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: solr

Hi i am setting SOLR search to my website. The SOLR remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request while adding indexing. Even after using earliest version of solrnet. 
Thanks

Comment: Please add more details to this question...It's meaningless right now.